# Unfortunately, program has stopped

Tags: java, android, crash

## **Unfortunately, program has stopped**

I was trying to calculate age in android studio. It doesn't show any error message but when I click on the "Button" , the app crashes and shows **"Unfortunately, Test1 has stopped."**

*Why my program is crashing even though it does not show any error message during compiling?*

The java code is like below

```
package android.example.com.test1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

public void hi() {

    Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 3, 1);
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 2, 28);

    int res = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if ((cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) > now.get(Calendar.MONTH))
            || (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == now.get(Calendar.MONTH) && cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > now
            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))) {
        res--;
    }


    TextView s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    s.setText(" " + res);
}

}
```

The xml code is like following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="android.example.com.test1.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message"
        android:onClick="hi"
        android:text="Button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Compiling only shows the syntax is correct. It does not mean the code is correct or doesn't contain logic errors or problems. Compiling does not mean *works*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong signature to setup click listener, it should be

```
public void hi(View v){//...code}
//             ^^^^^^
```

[From Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents)

The method you declare in the android:onClick attribute must have a signature exactly as shown above. Specifically, the method must:

- Be public
- Return void
- Define a `View as its only parameter` (this will be the View that was clicked)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `onClick` method must use a method that receives a view as a parameter.

```
public void hi(View view) {

    Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 3, 1);
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 2, 28);

    int res = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if ((cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) > now.get(Calendar.MONTH))
            || (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == now.get(Calendar.MONTH) && cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > now
            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))) {
        res--;
    }


    TextView s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    s.setText(" " + res);
}
```

Another way is to cast the button and overwrite the `onClick` method to call the hi () method. For this, you need to delete the `onClick` attribute of the XML.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button button  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            hi();
        }
    });
}

public void hi() {

    Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 3, 1);
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 2, 28);

    int res = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if ((cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) > now.get(Calendar.MONTH))
            || (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == now.get(Calendar.MONTH) && cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > now
            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))) {
        res--;
    }


    TextView s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    s.setText(" " + res);
}
```